# Represent hashmaps using an UML class diagram

Tags: java, hashmap, uml, class-diagram

I'm new to UML.  Does this class diagram represent correctly a `Hashmap<String, Hashmap<String, String>>` structure?

[image]

More precisely, the config property must be a struct like a `Hashmap<String, String>` (Java) or `dict[str, str]` (Python) and the `students` object must be a `Hashmap<String, Hasmap<String, String>>` (Java) or in Python `dict[str, dict[str, str]]` for instance. How to represent this structure (data types of the properties) using an uml class diagram?

What I tried to do in my diagram:  I've two times `M` because there is a class `M` and a class `M2D` which are used both. `M2D` maps a key of type `String` to `M`. `M` maps a key of type `String` to a `String`. In my understanding `M2D` represents `Hashmap<String, Hashmap<String, String>>`(Java Implemention) since `M` represents `Hashmap<String String>`.

Comment: Can you please clarify how the hash map would relate to the attributes in school, and what you try to achieve with a hash map of hasmaps ?  Because it is not clear if one of the hasp would correspond to an intermediary classe that is really needed or if it's just a solution to implement a more complex association.

Comment: No. There is no nesting.

Comment: What do you mean by nesting? The config property must be a struct like a Hashmap<String, String> (Java) or dict[str, str] (Python) and the students object must be a Hashmap<String, Hasmap<String, String>> (Java) or in Python dict[str, dict[str, str]] for instance. How to represent this structure (data types of the properties) using an uml class diagram?

Comment: A hash in a hash is a nesting and your diagram does not show any. Besides you have two times `M` which is ambiguous/wrong.

Comment: I've two times M because there is a class M and a class M2D which are used both. M2D maps a key of type String to M. M maps a key of type String to a String. Why there is no nesting? In my understanding M2D represents Hashmap<String, Hashmap<String, String>>(Java Implemention) since M represents Hashmap<String String>.

Comment: @Sven I've edited your question to bring in your comments.  With that we should be able to answer.  Keep in mind please for future question, that not everybody reads the comments and when critical information is missing in the question body,  there's a tendency to close-vote (already 2 close-votes before my edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What's the problem?

Reading your additional explanation in the comments, I understand that you try to have a very dynamic implementation, with a school having several dynamic configuration parameters, and students represented by a set of dynamic properties:

- In your implementation, these dynamic structures are easily and efficiently dealt with as hashmaps.
- However, in practice, one gets quickly lost by what is which hash map supposed to represent.  Now you're comfortable with it, but if you do another project and come back in 6 months you will understand what I mean.

The problem that you face in the modelling is that UML aims to help you provide clarity on your design, and not to visually program what's already in the code.

#### How to solve it?

I understand that the `config` in your `School` is in fact a set of config parameters, each identified by a unique key for a given school:

> The config property must be a struct like a Hashmap<String, String> (Java) or dict[str, str] (Python)

There are two approaches, both with config removed from the school attributes:

- use a qualifier (the small rectangle with a qualifier attribute `Key:String`) directly for the `School`, and associate it with a `String`,  or better with a `ConfigurationParameter` which would be a string, but could evolve into something more complex later.  This would be very close to your implementation.
- abstract from the way you implemented your configuration, and associate one school to many `ConfigurationElements`, which would be a class with a property `key`, and a property `parameter` both being strings.  This would allow other implementations as just the `Hashmap`.

For the more complex `Hashmap<String, Hasmap<String, String>>`, it's more challenging:

> the students object must be a Hashmap<String, Hasmap<String, String>> (Java) or in Python dict[str, dict[str, str]] for instance.

First of all, I see a `School` class and no `Student` class. But I see that you use a `students` property and note the plural. And you use a type M2D which we see you try to associate with a qualifier to something. So I think that your design forgets to show the design intent.  If the school has many students, then associate your school with a `Student` class.  Again:

- you could use a qualified association (e.g. if a student ID allows to find exactly one student for a school).  I'll use this in my diagram
- or you coud use a simple one to many association. This seems a better approach if the school acts as a kind of repository for the students, and if beyond a `getSudentdById(...):Student` you'd also want dome more creative queries, e.g. `getStudentsByAge(...):Student[*]`

Now, if your `Student` is implemented as a set of pair values (e.g. you don't want properties of a student to be fixed,  but dynamic),  then associate the `Student` with a qualifier to the `StudentAttribute` class which is a string.

The advantage is that this modelling makes the navigation in the `Hashmap<String, Hasmap<String, String>>` much clearer:  the first string gives a student,  the second string gives an attribute of a student which is a string.
[image]
Of course, you could remove the intermediates and associated directly to string, like the hashmap do,  but then you should at least add a comment to explain what the association with String is supposed to convey as information.